# How to call aggregate function in html using django

Tags: python, django

How to remove unnecessary words just like this **{'amount__sum': 480.0}** in my html ? i just want to print the value only.

this is my html

```
<span>{{total}}</span>
```

this is my views.py

```
.....
total = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter(
    id=itemID
).aggregate(
    total=Sum(
        F('unitprice') * quantity,
        output_field=FloatField(),
    )
)['total']

return render(request, "cart.html", {"total":total})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `aggregate` returns a dictionnay, you have to use your key, which is `total` as you defined here in the line : `total=Sum(`

So you can either change your html to :

```
<span>{{ total.total }}</span>
```

Or change the last line of your view to :

```
return render(request, "cart.html", {"total":total["total"]})
```